SwiftUI. GeometryReader overlaps views
I have view ItemView. This view must contains GeometryReader because i want hide the view when ItemView will be out of screen. (Some custom board)
struct ItemView: View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Long text here")
            Text("Long text hre")
        }
        .padding()
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .frame(minWidth: 350)
        .opacity(isVisible ? 1 : 0)
        .onChange(of: geometry.frame(in: .global)) { frame in
            /// some code here for checking x, y
        }
    }
}

I have parent view, where i add ItemView
func generateContent(by groups: [[ItemView]]) -> some View {
        return VStack {
            
            ForEach(groups, id:\.self) { group in
                
                HStack {
                    ForEach(group, id:\.self) { item in
                        ItemView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Problem: all my ItemViews are overlapping each other. If i remove GeometryReader from ItemView all will be work fine.
Question: How i can leave GeometryReader in ItemView without overlapping ItemView

A GeometryReader cannot be used to measure the size of views that it contains. However, a way to do this is to move the GeometryReader to the .background of a view instead. You should also not be passing an array (or array of arrays) of type View, but you could pass an array (or array of arrays) of type Item instead. If you could turn your code snippets into a complete reproducible example then it might be possible to help you to get it working. At the moment, ItemView does not compile and generateContent is missing the calling context.
